# My new employer wants to me to attend a meeting with their team

Tags: new-job, employer-relations, meetings, projects

I have accepted  a job offer and currently on notice period. My notice period is 2 months and alomost one third is completed. My new employer wants to me to attend a meeting with their team for a new upcoming project. Is it is good in IT industry to attend a meeting for upcoming employer before joining? Please advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with this. I've had to do it a few times when I've changed to different IT companies. It gives you a chance to meet the people you'll be working with, find out the technologies you'll be using and get an overview of what your project will be.

It's not quite clear from your question, but it sounds like you're suggesting you'll be required to take time off from your current role to attend this meeting, which could be a problem. You could speak to your current employers and ask if this is possible, although I wouldn't be surprised if the answer was no (although you never know without asking!).

If that is the case, speak to your new employees and explain this situation to them. Explain that you'd love to know more about the project, but you can't take the time off. They can either record the meeting for you (if the technology is available) or simply email you the minutes from the meeting. They obviously are aware of your notice period as it will have been raised when they hired you, so I can see no reason this would be a problem.

All of this information should help prepare you for the role you're going into by giving you time to do any initial background research/reading you want to and by showing you things like the coding practices and work environment of your new company.

Answer (score 3):

*In theroy* you are not an employee yet, so you are not obliged to take part, and if you take part you would *theoretically* be entitled to be paid for your presence.

But *in practice* it would make a good impression when you just show up. It seems to be an important meeting for the project you will take part in. So your presence will be beneficial for you and all future project participants.

But should you be unable to attend because your current employer won't let you, it will likely be understood.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it is good in IT industry to attend a meeting for upcoming employer
>   before joining?

It's a great thing to do, if your schedule and current contract allow for it. It's something I have done myself.

It demonstrates that you are eager to get started, excited about your new role and company, and are willing to extend yourself. It's a great way to get off to a fast start. Your new boss, and your new colleagues will probably appreciate it.

As long as you aren't expected to make any binding decisions, or to do any real work before you have fully joined, I see no downside to this - only benefits.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd ask at what time and on what day the meeting is going to take place and how long that meeting will last. Because depending on timing and location - hopefully both your new and current employers are close by - you might get away with taking time off from your current employer to attend the meeting. But even if the coast looks clear at the moment and indications are that you can make that meeting, something might happen at your current employer that might get you tied up in knots for all of that day when you said you were going to show up. Hopefully, your new employer understands that you are making a best effort to attend but that you can't make a guarantee that you can attend. Your new employer is probably operating on the principle "If I don't ask, I am not going to get" and that's fine. Give attending that meeting your best shot and if it turns out that it's not doable, it is what it is and that's fine, too.